# Import library jqGrid wih Meteor (NPM)

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, jqgrid

I perfom a project with Meteor and I would like use [free-jqgrid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid) .

***But*** I don't know how I can import this library correctly...

I was try :

- `import 'free-jqgrid';`
- `import jqGrid from 'free-jqgrid';`
- `import 'free-jqgrid/js/jquery.jqgrid.min';`

In my code I use qGrid like this "Getting started" :

```
angular.element('#grid').jqGrid({
    colModel: [
// ...
```

And I get this error, on the client :
`Error: angular.element(...).jqGrid is not a function`

Any kind of idea ? :-)

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you describe more exactly what you do? No released version of web browsers supports now `import` of modules. One can now makes some tests in *preliminary versions* of web browsers (see [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/)), but I suppose you don't do this. I suppose that you use Systemjs, webpack or some other produces which works like pre-processor of JavaScript. One have to use configuration of the products to configure module mapping. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/SystemJs3_4.14.0-jquery-ui1.12.1.htm) is an example of usage SystemJs.

Comment: Generally, you should add npm package to meteor project using `meteor npm install free-jqgrid`, then that library will be listed in `package.json` file of your app. But in this case even though this package was added in `node_moduels` folder, it was not listed in `package.json` file. Can you try `import * as jqGrid from free-jqgrid` and see if works for you.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg and @Sudheer for your response. 
@Sudheer, this package has been listed into package.json for me: `"free-jqgrid": "^4.14.0",`. With your solution, the variable jqGrid is an empty Object. And with `import jqGrid from 'free-jqgrid';`, jqGrid variable is equal to `function require<.node_modules["free-jqgrid"].js["jquery.jqgrid.src.js"]</</module.exports()`. 

I'm lost for the best way to import jqGrid and how I could use `$('table').jqGrid()`... without the error `.jqGrid is not a function`. :/

Comment: **You should provide the demo, which demonstrates the problem**. I repeat that replacement of `import jqGrid from 'free-jqgrid'` to `function require<.node_modules["free-jqgrid"].js["jquery.jqgrid.src.j‌​s"]</</module.export‌​s()` is not the part of JavaScript. You use directly or indirectly module like SystemJs and you should add the configuration (see [here](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md), for example), which describe logical name of the package used in `import` to the path of the corresponding js file.

Comment: I was try some things with your explanations, but no way... [Here](https://framagit.org/AurelienC/meteor-free-jqgrid) a simple Meteor project with `free-jqgrid` for exposeto you the problem. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Oleg.

## Meteor package for free-jqGrid

I was fork [meteor-jqGrid] (https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) package and I adapted this for free-jqgrid. I published this on :

- [Github (AurelienC/meteor-free-jqGrid)](https://github.com/AurelienC/meteor-free-jqGrid)
- [Atmosphere (aurelienc:free-jqgrid)](https://atmospherejs.com/aurelienc/free-jqgrid/)

Simply add on Meteor project with the following command into project folder : `meteor add aurelienc:free-jqgrid`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not use Meteor myself. Moreover I use requireJs or SystemJs instead of CommonJS modules. It could be that free-jqgrid has currently some problems in usage as CommonJS module.

Nevertheless I installed Meteor environments and made some tests. As the result I can suggest you the following workaround. You can insert the line

```
jqGrid(window,$);
```

directly after

```
import jqGrid from 'free-jqgrid';
```

or after

```
import jqGrid from 'free-jqgrid/js/jquery.jqgrid.src';
```

if you prefer to use non-minimized source of jqGrid.

You should not forget to import/include jQuery UI CSS or Bootstrap CSS and to import free-jqgrid CSS too:

```
import 'free-jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css';
```

Additionally you can consider to load jQuery UI CSS, Font Awesome and free jqGrid **from CDN**. See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) and [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) for more details.